# "Uncaught ReferenceError: TodoList is not defined" as I tried to call Todolist.deployed() in truffle console

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I was trying [this Beginner tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coQ5dg8wM2o&t=659s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) on smart contracts and solidity. I typed `truffle compile, truffle migrate` and they ran without any error and I got my gas cost used up in Ganache. When I opened truffle console and typed `TodoList = await TodoList.deployed()` as per the tutorial, I faced this error below:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: TodoList is not defined     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:7`

As per the tutorial, my 2_deploy_contracts.js looks like this

```
const TodoList = artifacts.require("TodoList.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TodoList);
};
```

Let me know what am I doing wrong, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const TodoList = artifacts.require("TodoList"); // Enter your Contract Name not File name

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TodoList);
};
```

Comment: This worked for me, I messed up with the cases in the contract name and got confused as to the requirement, thanks!